# Swiper - Protruding slide from the next/prev group of 2 slides is not visible until click next/prew

Tags: javascript, css, swiper.js

Swiper.js - How to make two slides in a group in the center, with the next and previous slides sticking out, with using loop in Swiper.js? **The main problem** is that the protruding slide from the next/prev group disappears, and appears suddenly only after pressing the next/prev buttons:
[JPG - protruding slide from the next group disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPiu0.jpg)

(JS) My Swiper.js config:

```
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
    loop: true,
    slidesPerView: 2,
    slidesPerGroup: 2,
    spaceBetween: 30,
    speed: 2000,
  
    pagination: {
        el: ".swiper-pagination",
        clickable: true,
      },
  
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
  });
```

(CSS) To see sticking out slides of the next/prev groups styles:

```
.swiper {
    margin: 0px 15%;
    overflow: inherit;
}
```

Here's what it looks like:
[JPG - carousel and margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KfLC.jpg)

(HTML) I have an even number of slides (6):

```
<div class="swiper">
   <div class="swiper-wrapper">
       <!-- Slides -->
                    
       <div class="swiper-slide">1</div>
       <div class="swiper-slide">2</div>
       <div class="swiper-slide">3</div>
       <div class="swiper-slide">4</div>
       <div class="swiper-slide">5</div>
       <div class="swiper-slide">6</div>
                    
    </div>
    <!-- If we need pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
                
    <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe just look for an alternative carousel script. For example, it would be this easy using the Carousel from the Fancyapps UI - https://jsfiddle.net/2s7j046d/

Answer (score 0):

If I recall well, when using `loop: true,` try also playing around the value of the option [loopAdditionalSlides](https://v8.swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-loopAdditionalSlides)

> `loopAdditionalSlides`:   *number* `0`
> *Additional number of slides that will be cloned after creation of loop*

```
loopAdditionalSlides: 2, // Adjust as needed
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention and help, but now it works like this: 
for next: 1,2 -> 5,6 -> 1,2 -> 5,6 ...
for prev is ok: ... 6,5 <- 4,3 <- 2,1 <- 6,5 ...
I adjusted the value 'loopAdditionalSlides' in different ways, there was always strange behavior. If I put more than 3, then next btn stops working after scrolling all 6